# Is my approach to this set theory proof correct?

Tags: proof-verification

Prove: For all sets A, B, C, if B ∩ C ⊆ A, then (C - A) ∩ (B - A) = ∅.

**Since B ∩ C is a subset of A, B is a subset of A.**

**Since B ∩ C is a subset of A, C is a subset of A.**

**Since B is a subset of A, subtracting A from B will result in the empty set.**

**Since C is a subset of A, subtracting A from C will result in the empty set.**

**The empty set intersected with the empty set equals the empty set.**

---

NEW:

Let x belong to (C - A) ∩ (B - A)

C - A = C ∩ A^c

B - A = B ∩ A^c

x belongs to (C ∩ A^c) ∩ (B ∩ A^c)

x belongs to C ∩ A^c ∩ B ∩ A^c

x belongs to B ∩ C ∩ A^c ∩ A^c

x belongs to B ∩ C ∩ A^c

Since B ∩ C is a subset of A, B ∩ C ∩ A^c is a subset of A ∩  A^c (the empty set)

Since x belongs to B ∩ C ∩ A^c, x belongs to the empty set.

Trivial: The empty set is a subset of (C - A) ∩ (B - A)

(C - A) ∩ (B - A) = ∅

QED

Comment: "$B \cap C$ belongs to $A$" is somewhat sloppy language since they're both sets.

Comment: fixed it a little bit. look better?

Comment: Looks reasonable now.

Answer (score 1):

The first bolded sentence is not a valid conclusion: for example, consider $A = \{ 1, 2 \}$, $B = \{ 1, 3 \}$, $C = \{ 1, 4 \}$.  Then $B \cap C = \{ 1 \} \subseteq A$ but $B$ is not a subset of $A$.

Comment: I knew it seemed too simple. Any tips on how to start this then?

Comment: $\emptyset \subseteq (C - A) \cap (B - A)$ is trivial.  For the other inclusion, start by assuming $x \in (C - A) \cap (B - A)$...

Comment: Before I try anything quick question: if A ⊆ B ∩ C (switching the order), could I say that A ⊆ B and A ⊆ C?

Comment: @Hello Yes (and in fact, $A \subseteq B \cap C$ *if and only if* $A \subseteq B$ and $A \subseteq C$).

Comment: Is this element argument you are referring to? Yes I agree proving the empty set is a subset is trivial, so now I should assume x is in (C - A) ∩ (B - A) and then show that x belongs to the empty set to prove equality?

Comment: will update the original post with my new approach.....

Comment: see the original post! thoughts?

Comment: What I was thinking was something along the lines: assume $x \in (C - A) \cap (B - A)$.  Then $x \in C - A$ so $x \in C$ but $x \not\in A$; and similarly, $x \in B - A$ so $x \in B$ but $x \not\in A$.  Since $x \in B$ and $x \in C$, then $x \in B \cap C$, so $x \in A$.  We now have a contradiction since also $x \not\in A$.  So, since a contradiction implies anything, $x \in \emptyset$.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly notice that your statement of the following statement is NOT true: "Since B ∩ C is a subset of A, B is a subset of A."

Notice $C \setminus A= C \cap A^c$

Thus $(C \setminus A) \cap (B \setminus A) = C \cap B \cap A^c$

Since $B \cap C \subset A$, then $B \cap C \cap A^c = \emptyset$

Comment: What does the backslash mean?

Comment: @Hello Just mean set minis, like $C - A$ as you wrote